# How applicate a specific format to each element of a vector

Tags: r

I have this vector of 84 x:

```
> y<-1:84
> v<-(paste(y,'x',collapse=''))
> v
[1] "1 x2 x3 x4 x5 x6 x7 x8 x9 x10 x11 x12 x13 x14 x15 x16 x17 x18 x19 x20 x21 x22 x23 x24 x25 x26 x27 x28 x29 x30 x31 x32 x33 x34 x35 x36 x37 x38 x39 x40 x41 x42 x43 x44 x45 x46 x47 x48 x49 x50 x51 x52 x53 x54 x55 x56 x57 x58 x59 x60 x61 x62 x63 x64 x65 x66 x67 x68 x69 x70 x71 x72 x73 x74 x75 x76 x77 x78 x79 x80 x81 x82 x83 x84 x"
```

Then I need to create a list from the vector above where each element of it has the format

```
~ exp(x)
```

In another word, I need to create a list contains elements like this,

```
~ exp(x1), ~ exp(x2), ~ exp(x3), ~ exp(x4),.....,~ exp(x84)
```

I tried using `apply`, `sapply` .. But no way!

what should I do please?
thank you in advance!

Comment: hi i am not quite sure if i understood your question correctly, but if i did this should work `paste0("~exp(x",1:81,")")`

Comment: @Joyvalley, thank you very much this is what I need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the comment, use: `paste0("~exp(x",1:81,")")`. Also, if you want it as a list as you say you want, add `as.list`, i.e. `as.list(paste0("~exp(x",1:81,")"))`